# preg_match - finding data

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match

I have a mysql database with php running a query on the table. I need to output the measurement of each order.

An example row would be `"this order contains 3x6lb of flour"`. I need to get the `3x6lb`. However, some results are also `"this order contains 3 x 6lb of flour"`. The possible weights are `lb` and `oz`.

Output should look like:

```
$rownum | $measurement
1 | 3x6lb
2 | 5x10oz
```

Comment: So, what's the question?  Have you tried anything yet?  Where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: I'm not sure how to properly use preg_match. The potential spacing between the numbers and x is throwing me off. As well as some having LB or lb or OZ or oz.

Comment: You'll just have to make a regex that handles different units.  Do you know how to make regexes?

Comment: So, describe the syntax (pattern) of all possible strings to match. `N x M {lb|oz}` with or without spaces, lower or upper case? Any other legal patterns? Integers only, or numbers in general? Spelled out units (pound, ounce)?

Comment: No spelled out units. It will be integers only, ie 1, 2, 5, 10. Can be both upper or lower case.

Answer (score 1):

[This expression](http://regex101.com/r/wF9mQ6):

```
(\d+)\s*x\s*(\d+)\s*(lb|oz)
```

Will capture 1+ digit, followed by 0+ whitespace, followed by `x`, followed by 0+ whitespace, capturing 1+ digit, followed by 0+ whitespace, and finally capturing your `lb` or `oz` unit (case-insensitive with the `i` modifier).

---

**PHP:**

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'rownum' => 1,
        'measurement' => '3x6lb',
    ),
    array(
        'rownum' => 2,
        'measurement' => '5 x 10 oz',
    ),
);

foreach($data as $row) {
    if(preg_match('/(\d+)\s*x\s*(\d+)\s*(lb|oz)/i', $row['measurement'], $matches)) {
        echo $row['rownum'] . ': ' . $matches[0];

        $matches[1]; // 3
        $matches[2]; // 6
        $matches[3]; // lb
    }
}
```

[`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) will return `true`/`false` if a match is found..then the entire match will be in `$matches[0]` with each part being in the keys `1-3`.

Comment: Your regex won't match `3 x 6lb`.

Comment: Oops! Good catch @RocketHazmat, that was a typo -- I even had it in my textual explanation of the regex ;)

Comment: the match seems to work when tested with one row, but getting the data into the array is not outputting anything. For some reason, PHP is not showing me any error messages either. I have error_reporting on the php file.

Comment: What is your end goal?  I made some psuedo-code based off of the limited information you showed (just 2 rows of data).  If you update your question, I may be able to better tailor my answer.

Comment: Got it to work. Had the , at the end of the last array. Thanks for your help!